# Please help me in this javascript for 'read more' link of post summary

Tags: javascript

I am using this code on my blogger blog.
This is the javascript-

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var thumbnail_mode = & quot;
    yes & quot;; //yes -with thumbnail, no -no thumbnail
    summary_noimg = 430; //summary length when no image
    summary_img = 340; //summary length when with image
    img_thumb_height = 200;
    img_thumb_width = 200;
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
    function removeHtmlTag(strx, chop) {
        if (strx.indexOf("<") != -1) {
            var s = strx.split("<");
            for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                if (s[i].indexOf(">") != -1) {
                    s[i] = s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf(">") + 1, s[i].length);
                }
            }
            strx = s.join("");
        }
        chop = (chop < strx.length - 1) ? chop : strx.length - 2;
        while (strx.charAt(chop - 1) != ' ' && strx.indexOf(' ', chop) != -1) chop++;
        strx = strx.substring(0, chop - 1);
        return strx + '...';
    }

    function createSummaryAndThumb(pID) {
        var div = document.getElementById(pID);
        var imgtag = "";
        var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
        var summ = summary_noimg;
        if (thumbnail_mode == "yes") {
            if (img.length >= 1) {

                imgtag = '<span style="float:left; padding:0px 10px 5px 0px;">
<img src="' + img[0].src + '" width="' + img_thumb_width + 'px" height="' + img_thumb_height + 'px"/>
</span>';
                summ = summary_img;
            }
        }
        var summary = imgtag + '<div>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML, summ) + '</div>';
        div.innerHTML = summary;
    }
    //]]>
</script>
```

And this is the code i am using in div of post element

```
<div expr:id='&quot;summary&quot; + data:post.id'>
    <data:post.body/>
</div>
<a class='more' expr:href='data:post.url'> read more </a>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    createSummaryAndThumb( & quot; summary < data: post.id / > & quot;);
</script>
```

**This is the result:**

Twitter is the second most popular social networking site. It is used by celebrities all around world. It is also called a microblogging website...
 **read more**

I want read more link just after ' **...**'  for example- 
 It is also called a microblogging website... **read more**

How can i do it, please help me.

Comment: Disregarding the code for a moment, can you list what you are trying to accomplish?  I took another look.  Is it just that the text is not aligned the way you want?

Comment: No i know how to align this text. But i want to know how can be read more text will be placed just after ...

Comment: So, you want the anchor aligned to the right of the div content, where  the div content ends with a ..., correct?

Comment: See my answer below and please accept if it works for you.  Works for me locally.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just one solution of many, but give your div prior to the anchor a display:inline; css styling and the anchor will fall to the right of the div content.  Either in another included css file, in a style tag, or within the div tag place a style="display:inline".

Comment: <div style = "display:inline;"> Your text here... </div>
    <a href='asdfasdf'>Read More</a> does not work?